# manipulate output of int2str

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

Is it possible for a for-loop like the one below, to display the value `001` for `i=1`

```
 for i=1:999
    disp(int2str(i))
 end
```

The context: I have ALOT of 2 dimensional matrices with the valibal name `Depth_xxxxxx_xxx`.
Loading them all into oné 3 dimensional matrix.

```
kk = 1;
for ii=0:999999
    for jj = 0:999
        try 
         a(:,:,kk) = eval(['Depth_' int2str(ii) '_' int2str(jj)]);
         kk = kk+1;
        end
    end 
end
```

Any other solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `sprintf`

```
for i=1:999
    disp(sprintf("%03d",i));
end
```

In your actual code:

```
...
a(:,:,kk) = eval(['Depth_' sprintf("%06",ii) '_' sprintf("%03",jj)]);
...
```

Comment: @MaltheEisum Both `'` and `"` works for me. I am compiling in Octave. Should have worked for you. Did that give any error?

Comment: @MaltheEisum - Note that [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) also accepts a format specifier if that is more friendly.